# PHP, How to find next greater key value from array

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
$pricing = array(
                 "2" => 8.23,
                 "5" => 10.97,
                 "10" => 13.28,
                 "15" => 15.40,
                 "20" => 18.15,
                 "25" => 20.36,
                 "30" => 22.84,
                 "40" => 25.60,
                 "50" => 28.35,
                 "60" => 31.89,
                 "70" => 36.23,
                 "80" => 39.40,
                 "90" => 42.52,
                 "100" => 44.75
                );
```

And I have a variable that has the client given value from 1 to 100.

Question is: what is the best and fastest way to find the next biggest key, if the key itself doesn't exist?

E.g. I have a variable with value of 12, and I need to get the price for that. According to the array here, the price would be 15.40 because the next biggest key is 15.

I could try and find key number '12', and if it doesn't exist, i would add one(12+1) and try again, until next key is found, but is there any function that could do this for me, or something even better/faster?

**Edit**: Clarification about the structure of the array.

Array is like it is in the example here. Keys are ordered as can be seen.

Comment: `foreach ($pricing as $key => $value)`, `if ($key >= $needle) break;` - these are the two essential building blocks you can use to put together a simple solution.

Comment: @deceze is correct, foreach is probably the fastest and simplest code for this. You should probably set $price = $value; and check $price with isset().

Comment: @mc.watras Edited the question a bit. I don't see how the values affect, but they are as same as the example. Keys are ordered, like in the example. Edit: Sorry, I had mixed the values and keys. Edited again. :)

Comment: It seems the good ol' for-loop is the way to go here. Simple problems rarely need complex solutions I guess.

Comment: What should happen with 101? Should it return the last value? Nothing? Error?

Comment: @Ja͢ck Client only gives values from 1 to 100. This can be seen in the question.

Comment: You said it needs to find the next biggest value if the key itself can't be found. But if it goes above the highest key it should return that, right?

Comment: @Ja͢ck I'm not being clear it seems. :) 
If the client gives key-value of 100, the function should return value corresponding the key "100", which is 44.75. There will be no 101 coming from the client.
But if client gives key-value of 99, the function should return value from the key "100", since 99 cannot be found, and the next biggest is "100".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `foreach` will do, but to guard against either empty arrays or a needle that's higher than the highest key, here's an implementation that will cover that as well:

```
function find(array $pricing, $needle)
{
    $last = null; // return value if $pricing array is empty

    foreach ($pricing as $key => $value) {
        if ($key >= $needle) {
            return $key; // found it, return quickly
        }
        $last = $key; // keep the last key thus far
    }

    return $last;
}

$result = find($pricing, 12); // 15
$result = find($pricing, 101); // 100
$result = find([], 12); // null
```

Comment: All of the codes presented seem to work nicely, so the selection of the winner goes to the one that has the similar coding-style as I do. I cannot remember when was the last time I used do-while. :)
 Thanks to all who contributed!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are looking for the 'requiredKey' and that the array is sorted by key

This seem to do what you want.

Code:

```
<?php

$pricing = array(
                 "2" => 8.23,
                 "5" => 10.97,
                 "10" => 13.28,
                 "15" => 15.40,
                 "20" => 18.15,
                 "25" => 20.36,
                 "30" => 22.84,
                 "40" => 25.60,
                 "50" => 28.35,
                 "60" => 31.89,
                 "70" => 36.23,
                 "80" => 39.40,
                 "90" => 42.52,
                 "100" => 44.75
                );

// What key we want...
$requiredKey =  12;

// outout in here
$foundKey   = -1;
$foundValue = -1;

// always run the loop once...
do {
    $foundKey = key($pricing);        // store the current details
    $foundValue = current($pricing);

    next($pricing); // will be equal or greater
}
while (   current($pricing) !== false
        && $foundKey < $requiredKey);


echo '<pre>';
echo '<br />', 'key: ', $foundKey, ' value: ',  $foundValue;
echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
key: 15 value: 15.4
```

Comment: Why not just use `foreach()` and break when the condition is met?

Comment: remember to sort array by key before use this loop.

Comment: @jack, There is no special reason why I choose not to use a foreach loop. The run time cost in the worse case is one full scan of the array. The loop will end as soon as the key is found and will return the correct values. So, on average it will scan half the array. It could be worthwhile adding a separate check for the `isset[$key]` before the loop for best efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is ok, you can do it using next()
http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php

```
$search = 12;
$pricing = array(
                 "2" => 8.23,
                 "5" => 10.97,
                 "10" => 13.28,
                 "15" => 15.40,
                 "20" => 18.15,
                 "25" => 20.36,
                 "30" => 22.84,
                 "40" => 25.60,
                 "50" => 28.35,
                 "60" => 31.89,
                 "70" => 36.23,
                 "80" => 39.40,
                 "90" => 42.52,
                 "100" => 44.75
                );

$result = null;
if (!isset($pricing[$search])) {
  do {
   } while (next($pricing) && $search > key($pricing));
    $result = current($pricing);
} else {
   $result = $pricing[$search];
}

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your lookup array will not change so it makes perfect sense to declare it as a constant (instead of a variable) and to make your code immediately understandable, give the constant a self-explanatory name.

```
const THRESHOLD_PRICES = [
    2 => 8.23,
    5 => 10.97,
    10 => 13.28,
    15 => 15.40,
    20 => 18.15,
    25 => 20.36,
    30 => 22.84,
    40 => 25.60,
    50 => 28.35,
    60 => 31.89,
    70 => 36.23,
    80 => 39.40,
    90 => 42.52,
    100 => 44.75
];
```

A valuable benefit of using a constant is that it is not necessary to explicitly pass the data into a function's scope.

In your function, I recommend type hinting the parameter and the return value -- again to make the code easier to understand.

Before iterating the array, do a quick scan of the keys for an exact match.  Because of the way that php treats arrays as hashmaps, this is a very low-cost technique.

Next iterate the array and break the loop as soon as the array key is larger than the search value.

Regardless of if/when the loop breaks, the final iteration will declare the targeted price, so unconditionally return that float value.

```
function getThresholdPrice(int $search): float {
    if (isset(THRESHOLD_PRICES[$search])) {
        return THRESHOLD_PRICES[$search];
    }
    foreach (THRESHOLD_PRICES as $threshold => $price) {
        if ($threshold > $search) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Tests: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VAZvY))

```
foreach (range(1, 105, 13) as $test) {
    printf("%d => %.02f\n", $test, getThresholdPrice($test));
}
```

Output:

```
1 => 8.23
14 => 15.40
27 => 22.84
40 => 25.60
53 => 31.89
66 => 36.23
79 => 39.40
92 => 44.75
105 => 44.75
```